# Button not clickable when top position adjusted

Tags: html, css

For some reason, when i add the 'top: xxx' property in css my button becomes unclickable, and i cant position it correctly. It was working fine before. I have it set up to run joyride onclick, which is a foundation plug in. Not sure whats going on. Here's my html, and link to the site, please inspect element to see code www.omegadesignla.com:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>

      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="large-3 small-centered columns"> <!-- large centered -->
        <a id="topbutton" class="button large radius button">Take the tour!</a>

        </div>



      </header>
```

Here is my css:

```
#topbutton{
    position: relative;
    top: 125px;
 }
```

Comment: You havent posted enough for anyone to try and diagnose the issue. You dont say what the click event is or how it is delegated. Show more code or a fiddle.

Comment: have you also considered including an href attrib on you anchor tag?

Comment: i added a link to the page, please see the link there is too much code to post and im not sure which to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your just missing an href attribute inside the 
try this

```
<a id="topbutton" href="#" class="button large radius button">Take the tour!</a>
```

Comment: really? because I tried your code 1st and its really not clickable until I added the `href` .. can you post your complete code?

Comment: yeah i posted the site code and added href, still doesnt work.

Comment: is it possible that your div container 1 is the problem? can you remove it temporarily for the sake of testing

Comment: ALSO i Think its missing 1 closing div i think

Comment: yeah i commented out container1 and that fixed the problem! Wierd.

Comment: have you also included the additional close tag for the div on the #container?

Comment: im not sure to be honest i got lost in a sea of divs

Comment: It's fixed now, I am confused to why it was the container1 causing the problem, if u want to add it as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: just after  `</header>` add a close div.. and if that does not work consider resizing the height of your #container1 and its position

Comment: i just commented out the container1 because it wasnt even being used it was commented out in my css and it worked after i commented it out. lol